# Uncaught (in promise) ... when using catch

Tags: javascript, promise

Why does the following code report an `Uncaught (in promise) rejected` error when it is being caught?

```js
function Test() {
  this.start = function(action) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (action == "fail") return reject("rejected");
        resolve("resolved");
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}

const test = new Test();
const promise = test.start("fail");
promise.then(console.log);
promise.catch(console.error);
```

The output (in a browser) is:

`rejected` from the catch()

`Uncaught (in promise) rejected` from the call to reject

Comment: if you use `promise.then(console.log).catch(() => {});` there is nothing displayed in the console, you need to chain it or it does not work, like `promise.then(console.log);promise.catch(() => {});` will not work

Comment: Your need is not very clear. Please tell what you want so we can help you 

Comment: @alexzerah I think it is clear to me.

Comment: I personnaly don't get what you ask.
Do you want :
- an explanation ?
- a correction of code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're *forking* your promise chain:

```
promise ---> .then( .. ) ---> ???
        \
         \
          +-> .catch( .. )
```

The rejection is being caught by the `.catch` just fine, but it *also* goes through the `.then` branch. Both of those branches are resolved independently. And you're not catching the rejection on the `.then` branch, leading to the uncaught rejection error.

Compare with:

```
promise.then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

Here the chain looks like this:

```
promise ---> .then( .. ) ---> .catch( .. )
```

The rejection will *skip* the `.then` handler and go to the nearest `.catch`.

Comment: Very nicely put :) +

Answer (score 3):

Ok. The answer is obvious, yet easy to miss.

`.then(...)` returns another promise. So you have to attach the `.catch(...)` to THAT.

Solution:

```
const promise = test.start("fail");
promise.then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

OR more explicitly:

```
const promise = test.start("fail");
const promise2 = promise.then(console.log);
promise2.catch(console.error);
```

---

`@deceze`'s answer/explaination is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code :

```js
function Test() {
  this.start = function(action) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (action == "fail") return reject(new Error("rejected"));
        resolve("resolved");
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}

const test = new Test();
const promise = test.start("fail");
promise.then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

you need to chain .then() and .catch() for it to work,

because .then() will return a new promise, and it's that promise that will throw the error you need to catch

Comment: I think the OP needs the elaboration/explaination, rather than the 'quick fix'. I already new this corrected code which I could've posted in the first minute, but the explaination is more important.

Comment: Yes. I want to know why adding a catch to the top level promise (the one that's being rejected) which does call the catch handler, is reporting that the rejection was unhandled (it clearly was handled - or not given of @deceze's answer).

Comment: Well the second one is unhandled, .then() will return a promise and you will need to catch that one also

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no promise made for your .then

Either you change your function call into

```
promise.then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

or
change your reject into resolve on your promise

```
function Test() {
    this.start = function(action) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (action == "fail") return resolve("rejected");
                return resolve("resolved");
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: don't call resolve with a "rejected" value it does not make sense

Comment: it's either. unless you change the function call. 
because there's no handler for the then function.

Comment: it's not either, it's just no, don't ever do that, that's bad practice

Comment: I just answer his question why there's uncaught promise. 
That's why posted my first answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your code says the following:

```js
const test = new Test();
const promise = test.start("fail");
```

You create a promise and give a string parameter ("fail").

```js
promise.then(console.log);
promise.catch(console.error);
```

You catch the promise and show the error

```js
if (action == "fail") return reject("rejected");
```

You return the reject function with the string parameter "rejected".

Hope it help.